# javascript regexp find particular sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

might be an easy question but i'm fairly new to regular expressions.

given a paragraph, i would like to locate a particular sentence that begins with the specified word and replace the entire sentence with something else.

how can i build a regexp to search for a sentence that begins with a particular word, which can be followed by a number of different words, and ends with a `.` (period).

for example, given the sentence `foo bar. foo3 bar3. foo2 bar2.`, find a substring that begins with `foo3`, has any number of words, and ends with `.`.

Comment: What if the sentence ends with other punctuation (like `!` or `?`)? Can the sentence contain decimal numbers or currency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
/(^|\.\s+)(foo3[^.]*\.)/
```

Searches for the period marking the previous sentence (or the beginning of the string in the case of the first sentence), followed by spaces, then the start character sequence (in this case, `foo3`), followed by all non-period characters leading up to the period ending that sentence.

Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/ROl2odiDn5

---

Here's how replacing the sentence might be implemented in practice:

```
var str = "foo bar. foo3 bar3. foo2 bar2.";
var regex = /(^|\.\s+)(foo3[^.]*\.)/g;
str = str.replace(regex, "$1new sentence.");
alert(str);
```

In this example, I use the regular expression replace and incorporate the extra matched characters (period from previous sentence) via `$1`, followed by the new sentence that is to replace the old sentence.  This ensures that the state of the other sentences in the paragraph remains unchanged.  Note also that this example will update all matching sentences, since I use the `/g`(global) flag.  If you only want to change the first sentence, remove the `g`, or make your sentence matching more specific by including more beginning words.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qPxFp/2/

Comment: That wouldn't work if it was the first sentence in the paragraph.

Comment: thank you mellamokb! i changed the regex slightly and was able to grab just the sentence. `/(foo3\s[^.]*\.)` and that's a great site. thanks for the link.

Comment: Note that the regex you are using will have the problems mentioned in @CodeJockey's post.  Just be aware that you will be allowing `foo3` to appear in the middle of a sentence instead of the beginning.  If you are using search strings that unambiguously appear only at the beginning of sentences, then you will be fine.

Comment: Two _potential_ problems: it will match up to a decimal number if it exists in the sentence (rather than get to the end of the sentence) _and_ it will also match sentences that start with `foo33` or even `foo3498672736-hhhhhhhh`

Comment: The gunslinger approach wins over the scholar approach again? :-D

Answer (score 0):

shortest/most-efficient I can think of:

```
/foo3\b[^.]*\./
```

However, that has a few problems:

- it will match up to a decimal number (like matching `foo3 contributed $4.` from `foo3 contributed $4.83 million to the campaign.`
- it will technically match foo3 anywhere in a sentence to the end of the sentence (like matching `foo3's guts.` in `I hate foo3's guts.`)
- it won't allow for sentences ending in exclamation points or question marks, for example

The following expression fixes these things - though it's a bit less efficient (by requiring some sort of whitespace or end-of-string after the punctuation):

```
/(^|[.!?]\s+)foo3\b.*?(?=[.!?](\s|$))[.!?]/
```

...replace with e.g.: `$1Replacement sentence.`